# modal not fully popping up in bootstrap 4 using .net mvc 4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-4

I have a modal that needs to pop up and display a video based on an ID but only the grey background of the modal pops up not the actual modal can you guys help me with this? The code is as follows:

```
                <div class="row">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="ajax@(Model.Movies.FirstOrDefault().MovieID)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ajax@(Model.Movies.FirstOrDefault().MovieID)">Watch Now</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Download <span class="fa fa-download"></span></button>
                </div>
                <br />
    <div class="modal fade" id="ajax@(Model.Movies.FirstOrDefault().MovieID)" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h3>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Movies.FirstOrDefault().Title)</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <video id="video" poster="~/Images/cool cat.jpg"
                           controls="controls"
                           loop="loop">
                        <source src="@Url.Content(Model.Movies.FirstOrDefault().VideoFilePath)" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="btnClose" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon-folder-close"></span>Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Download</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```